# How can I replace a GWT widget in a Panel?

Tags: dom, gwt

I have a Composite whose main widget has two children, thus:

```
public MyComposite() {
    child1 = new FlowPanel();
    child1.getElement().setId("child1");

    child2 = new FlowPanel();
    child2.getElement().setId("child2");

    panel = new FlowPanel();
    panel.add(child1);
    panel.add(child2);
    initWidget(panel);
}
```

Some time after construction of MyComposite, I want to swap child1 out, replacing it with another widget, new-child1.

I could perhaps remove child1 by calling panel.remove(child1), and then add my new widget by calling panel.add(new-child1); but this would cause child2 to be rendered first, wouldn't it?

So, how can I replace child1 with new-child1 without changing the order of panel's children?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `insert()` instead of `add()`.

Unfortunately, you can't call `insert()` since it's protected, so you need to extend `FlowPanel`:

```
public class UsefulFlowPanel extends FlowPanel {
    public void add (int index, Widget child) {
        insert (child, getElement(), index, true);
    }
}
```

should work.

Comment: Last time I looked insert was a public method: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlowPanel.html#insert%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget,%20int%29

Comment: Hmm... Google must have returned an old version of the docs for me, then.

Comment: Wasn't public in 1.5: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlowPanel.html